# Clearing NSUndoManager's Redo stack

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, undo-redo, nsundomanager, redo

In my application, there are some actions I want to undo programmatically, without giving the user the option of clicking "Redo". Is there any way to clear the Redo stack of `NSUndoManager`? If not, and I were to subclass `NSUndoManager`, is there any way to get access to the redo stack in order to clear it? I didn't see any way to from the documentation.

Alternately, is there a way to revert the changes from the current nested undo group without it populating the Redo stack? I'm already building a nested undo group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up taking a 2-step approach. The first step was to create a dummy undo item, which clears the Redo stack. Then, I just had to remove that undo item, and both stacks are clean.

I was able to use `self` as the dummy undo target, since I don't have any actual undo actions associated with the class containing the code. `self` could be replaced with any object that doesn't contribute to the Undo stack.

The trick was calling `removeAllActionsWithTarget` with a delay, otherwise it doesn't have an effect.

```
// End the open undo grouping
[undoManager endUndoGrouping];

// Perform the undo operation, which gets pushed onto the Redo stack
[undoManager undo];

// Add a dummy Undo item to clear the Redo stack
[undoManager registerUndoWithTarget:self selector:nil object:nil];

// Remove the dummy item with a delay, pushing it to the next run loop cycle
[undoManager performSelector:@selector(removeAllActionsWithTarget:)
                  withObject:self
                  afterDelay:0.0];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
[undoManager disableUndoRegistration];
[undoManager undo];
[undoManager enableUndoRegistration];
```

Comment: That causes an exception: "undo was called with too many nested undo groups", whether or not I close the only open undo grouping beforehand. Does this have to do with all of these calls being on the same cycle of the run loop?